# Using .htaccess to point absolute page links to directory instead of root domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My local development web server has all my different project folders, for example:

```
https://localhost/project1
https://localhost/project2
```

Due to dynamic content, some of my projects require absolute links, such as `/images/example.jpg` - when they are uploaded to my web server, under their appropriate domain they work perfectly, for example `domain.com/images/example.jpg`

However on my local server they do not, because they point to `localhost/images/example.jpg` (obviously), however I need the root directory to be viewed as `./project1` so I need the link to be interpreted as `localhost/project1/images/example.jpg`

My current solution is I have this in my root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /project1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

However this only lets me rewrite the links for one dynamic project folder at a time, which is problematic if I want to jump between projects.

How can I do this from .htaccess **in the project folder** so I can develop on my local server with ease without having to switch directories in the root .htaccess file?

Edit: with the help from arkascha I want to further clarify my question:

With .htaccess I would like to check if a file/directory is existent in the root directory (as seen in my example), if is not, I would like it to look for the file in the directory of the referrer (the first directory after root).

Comment: If there is no criteria present in the requests by which the rewriting engine could decide which project should be chosen, then how should it make that decision? Can you name any such criteria? I can't. Using different host names are one option, but that requires different certificates. Evaluating the referrer header is an option, but that is not robust, things might or might not work depending on the client setup.

Comment: I would like to come back to your initial statement though: "Due to dynamic content, some of my projects require absolute links ...". Why is that? Dynamic content is standard, that does _not_ automatically "require absolute links". In contrary. So are you really sure that assumption you make is correct? Because that is the cause of your issue. And it always is wise to cure the cause instead of trying to get along with the symptoms.

Comment: @arkascha - the referrer header works for me, if the file is not found then use the directory of the referrer header in my script above. It doesn't;t need to be robust, it just needs to work for me and my local development. And yes, it's just the way I wrote my code and I would prefer nto to rewrite it.

Comment: OK, so you have a solution that works for you. Great!

Comment: @arkascha - yeah, but I have no idea on how to do it, do you?

Comment: I added an answer below ...

Comment: @arkascha - I was able to refine my question with your help, could you update your answer accordingly?

Comment: See my second answer below which picks up my initial suggestion again: using separate local hosts for this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to the question this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://[^/]+/([^/]+)/
RewriteRule ^/?images/ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

You can implement such rules in the http server's host configuration, or, if you have no access to that, you can use a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess"), *if you have enabled the consideration of such for that http host* ...

Comment: This is real close, but I just need it to rewrite localhost/ to localhost/project1/ - I don't want the images because there's CSS, JS, and other files in different folders that I would want as well, just not stated in the example. (project one being the referfer directory)

Comment: Considering that I decided to post another answer. An answer that picks up my initial suggestion to use a setup based on separate hosts for local development. In my eyes that makes a whole lot more sense for what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the clarification you made in your question after I offered my first answer, I would like to bring my first suggestions to notice again: using different host names. To me this sounds like the more promising approach to your situation.

You can use different hostnames locally without much effort. And if this only is about your local development environment anyway, then you also don't need to care about valid ssl certificates.

You just need to take care that a name resolution for such host name succeeds. All operating systems offer means for that, but the details obviously differ slightly. Unless you made really surprising changes to your local name resolution setup you should have a "hosts" file in your system where local host names can be registered in a static manner along with the address those names should get resolved to. That is effective, easy to setup and solves your issue.

Given that you can define a local host for each of your projects. Thus requesting these hosts just like your projects would get requested in production. This way your development setup stays much closer to the actual production setup you implement your projects for.

This would be an example for such a "hosts" file, here on taken from a typical Linux based system:

```
# Host addresses
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1  bragi
::1        localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1    ip6-allnodes
ff02::2    ip6-allrouters
```

You can simply add entries there using any plain text editor, for example you could append:

```
127.0.0.1  project1
127.0.0.1  project2
```

All that is left is to setup separate virtual hosts for those projects inside your http server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project1

        LogLevel notice
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project1/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project1/access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/project1
        <Directory /var/www/hosts/project1>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project2

        LogLevel notice
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project2/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project2/access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/project2
        <Directory /var/www/hosts/project2>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That is all you need to request your local http server using different host names for different projects:

```
http://project1/foo
http://project2/bar
```

You could even use the `https` protocol locally using a snake oil certificate, you'd have to accept that certificate once for every project then in the browser used for testing.

---

The bottom line:

You use a host name per project, just as you do in production. This keeps your local development setup much closer to the actual production setup. You don't need any fancy rewriting rules.

I personally chose to include common, repeated configuration options for those virtual hosts in a shared configuration file I include in those host definitions above. But that is a question of personal choice, there are endless options, obviously. The documentation of the apache http server and all its glorious modules will answer all questions about that. That documentation is of excellent quality and comes with great examples, as typical for OpenSource projects.

Comment: This is a great solution, however adding projects would become tedious, is there anyway we can automatically use the referrer to select the proper document root? That way I would only have to add new projects in my host file and I can leave the htacess file alone as a set it and forget it type deal.

Comment: You can also use a fallback virtual host for this, then the task of adding virtual hosts is not required, though you lose the option to use custom settings for hosts.